# Textmarker effect over multiline

Tags: css

I'm using a nice textmarker effect css only. While this is working if the span starts and ends in one line (in this example `my`) it does not work in case the < span > runs over several lines (like with `something and sometimes I'm`). is it possible to apply the effect with strike::after over more than one line?

```css
article{
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 1rem;
  border: 1px dotted;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 1rem;
}


@keyframes strike{
  0%   { width : 0; }
  100% { width: 100%; }
}

.strike {
    position: relative;
}

.three::after {
    content: ' ';
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 16px;
    margin-top: -3px;
    background: rgba(237, 255, 33, 0.7);
    animation-name: strike;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

```html
<article class="col--padding js-click-link startpanel">
<p class="blog__body">Hello <span class="strike three">my</span> name is <span class="strike three">something and sometimes I'm</span> highlited</p>
</article>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to expand :after to the next line, but your effect can be built without any :after pseudo-classes, with background animation, like that:

```
@keyframes strike{
  0%   { background-size: 0 100%; }
  100% { background-size: 100% 100%; }
}

.three {
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(237, 255, 33, 0.7) 0, rgba(237, 255, 33, 0.7) 100%);
    background-size: 0 100%;
    background-position: 0 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
    animation-name: strike;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

So here I just append a solid background-image to your `.three` element and animate its background-size according to X-asis from 0% to the full width, and it works properly!

Check please [working code here](https://codepen.io/nat-davydova/pen/7336094c7e5fe7a536be4e661d5bed43), I've prepared a codepen for you!